# Facebook comments - Moderation link not showing

Tags: facebook-comments

I set up Facebook comments on a staging site we have, however can't get the Moderation Link to show up:

http://telegram_com.wtstage.sx.atl.publicus.com/article/20150426/NEWS/304269695?nocache=1

I have confirmed that I'm an administrator on the Facebook app account.

I have this in the header:

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1393680337622798" />`

I have this in the body:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=1393680337622798";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://telegram.com/article/20150426/NEWS/304269695/101116" data-numposts="25" data-version="v2.3" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

I have tried using the live telegram.com url as well as the staging url.

If I swap the url (data-href) for another site I am an administrator on, the Facebook comment moderation link shows up in the comment widget.  However if I use any url that is the telegram.com's, the Moderation link does not show up.

Is there a setting or something in Facebook's backend that I could be missing?  It seems to me the code would be correct, if it works when I use the same app id, but a different data-href url.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have the same issue using the data-href attribute, however, switching to the  init version of the comments plugin sorted my issue.

So now, I'm using the following towards the top of the page:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '516991728450336',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.3',
            num_posts: 5,
            width: '100%'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And I've got a

```
<div class="fb-comments"></div>
```

Further down the page. This way, I don't even need the `<meta property="fb:app_id"...` either, as that only overrides the appId in the FB.init script.

You can specify the href attribute in the script to modify the URL, but if you don't, it'll just default to your page URL. Further parameters [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings)

I hope it helps.